# Java and Prolog - Interprolog

Tags: java, prolog, interprolog

I am currently trying to set up interprolog(see http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/) and i've followed the steps on the site, but now I'm wondering how i can use interprologs classes from my eclipse ide? Do i need to import the classes into my project so i can use interprolog?? How can i go about doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `interprolog.jar` to the build path (located inside http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/interprolog212.zip)?

In Eclipse you accomplish this by:

1. Right click you project, select `Properties`
2. Choose `Java build path` in the left side view
3. Select the `Libraries` tab
4. Click `Add External Jar...` and locate the interprolog.jar file.

Now you should be able to use the API, for example by typing `new TermListModel` and have Eclipse add the `import com.declarativa.interprolog.gui.TermListModel` for you.